# Why CSS grid puts one more extra gap after the grid line ends?

Tags: css, css-grid

What I learned is that `grid-gap` is actually giving gaps between columns and/or rows.

My Grid has 6 columns and 6 rows therefore, if I set `column-gap`, there should be 5 gaps between columns. But in may case, there are 6 gaps. One more extra gap after grid-line ends.
Why does it happen?

[image]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 236, 233);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  /*width: 80%;
    margin:auto;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 0.5fr 3fr 1fr 3fr 2fr 0.5fr / repeat(6, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}


/* header */

header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 7;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>PupSpa</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="banner">
    <h2></h2>
    <img src=>
  </div>
  <div id="description">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box address">
    <img src="">
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box hours">
    <img src="">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="box call_us">
    <img src="">
    <h4></h4>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't see any problem I cleaned up your code a bit and filled all 6 rows. Instead of using the body I added a div which is the grid container. then removed margin and padding from body. This is my outcome:

[image: grid-container with 6 columns + rows and 5 gaps]

5 spacers vertically and 5 horizontally without additional space.

the html:

```
<div class="body">
    <header>
        <h1>PupSpa</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="banner">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <img src=>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box address">
        <img src="">
        <h3>a</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box hours">
        <img src="">
        <h4>b</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <img src=>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box address">
        <img src="">
        <h3>a</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box hours">
        <img src="">
        <h4>b</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <img src=>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box address">
        <img src="">
        <h3>a</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box hours">
        <img src="">
        <h4>b</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <img src=>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box address">
        <img src="">
        <h3>a</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box hours">
        <img src="">
        <h4>b</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <img src=>
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box address">
        <img src="">
        <h3>a</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box hours">
        <img src="">
        <h4>b</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box call_us">
        <img src="">
        <h4>c</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 236, 233);
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.body {
  /*width: 80%;
    margin:auto;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 0.5fr 3fr 1fr 3fr 2fr 0.5fr / repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}


/* header */

header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 7;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
}
```

working example: [here](https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/VwKdYJK)